# How to Load images on google cluster marker from url

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

My problem is how to load images from a URL on google cluster marker. I'm using Universal Image Loader to load this images on the imageView async, but the problems is that the images are not loaded on the marker that corresponds.

Anyone know about any example?

Could anyone help me from this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please share your code implementation? Are you getting any errors? Google's doc on customizing marker images can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker#customize_the_marker_image